# Testing a published Logistic Regression Model Equation with my own data

Tags: r, logistic, regression-coefficients

I have a dataset with the same dependent and independent variables as those for a logistic regression model whose equation has been published in the literature. How do I go about testing whether that equation fits well with my data, since their model was obviously fitted with a different dataset?

In other words I want to know if their model can be generalisable to a different sample/population.

I want to do this in R and all the searches I have done seem to only discuss how to fit a model with my data using the glm() function. I can fit a new model with my data and will therefore get different coefficients to those published, how do I then compare and contrast the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To externally validate a regression model, don't refit the model.  All model parameters should be "frozen".  Start with a rigorous full-resolution smooth nonparametric calibration plot to check absolute predictive accuracy.  There are various tests for calibration accuracy, the most powerful of which is probably Spiegelhalter's.  Both these methods and many more, including indexes of predictive discrimination, are automatically done by the R `rms` package's `val.prob` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was wondering also what your thoughts were on the Hosmer-Lemeshow goodness of fit test?

Comment: That test involves a very low-resolution calibration (crude binning of predicted probabilities into deciles, usually) and has too many degrees of freedom to have good power for smaller $N$.